# Protect Joomla SQL connection

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, joomla, sql-injection

I use this code for "check repeated ip" on my forum :

```
<?php 

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

    $pid = $forum['Post']['topic_id'];

    $ipaddress = $forum['User']['ipaddress'];

    $query = 'SELECT count(ipaddress) FROM #__forum_comments WHERE ipaddress = "' . $ipaddress . '" AND pid = ' . (int) $pid;

    $count_ip = $db->setQuery($query)->loadResult();

    if($count_ip >= 2){
    echo 'Your ip repeated';
    }

?>
```

I asked developers who wrote this code about protection of SQL injections and that's what they said:

> The native Joomla method is `JFactory::getDBO()` which is the right way to do it. You can try using the escape method to see if that works: `$ipaddress = $db->escape($forum['User']['ipaddress']);` There's no need to escape the `$pid` because casting it to an integer is enough. In fact, since both values come straight from the database it's pretty safe to assume that there cannot be any sort of mysql injection here even without escaping.

Do I need to do something like this ?

```
//escaping to prevent sql injection
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $review['Review']['listing_id']);
$ipaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $review['User']['ipaddress']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$pid = $jinput->get('pid', '', 'integer');
$ip =  $jinput->get('ip', '', 'string');
```

And then you can run your query.